# Monogame HandleInput isn't called on iOS device

Tags: ios, xamarin, monogame

I'm trying to port a game from Windows Phone into iOS with monogame and Xamarin. I stumbled upon a problem - the app doesn't react to any gestures. It works fine on an emulator but not on a real device. I checked this is set up properly

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I really can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: It could be a bug in MonoGame. Maybe post on the MonoGame forums and/or take a look at the MonoGame code on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating MonoGame.Framework dll to version 3.1.2.0 fixed this issue. I got it from flappy bird Xamarin monogame project.

http://blog.xamarin.com/flappy-valentines-day/